# error on async mongodb client vert.x

Tags: java, mongodb, vert.x

I use this code to connect to localhost mongodb database.
after connection when I want to retrieve data I get this exception.

```
SEVERE: com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.errorHandlingCallback(Lcom/mongodb/async/SingleResultCallback;)Lcom/mongodb/async/SingleResultCallback;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.errorHandlingCallback(Lcom/mongodb/async/SingleResultCallback;)Lcom/mongodb/async/SingleResultCallback;
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClientImpl$2.execute(MongoClientImpl.java:100)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.OperationIterable.batchCursor(OperationIterable.java:132)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.OperationIterable.into(OperationIterable.java:64)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.FindIterableImpl.into(FindIterableImpl.java:162)
    at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.MongoClientImpl.findWithOptions(MongoClientImpl.java:235)
    at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.MongoClientImpl.find(MongoClientImpl.java:217)
    at verticle.ServerVerticle.start(ServerVerticle.java:53)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.lambda$doDeploy$8(DeploymentManager.java:434)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$2(ContextImpl.java:316)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:418)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:440)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

my code:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClient.createShared(vertx, config().getJsonObject("mongodb"));
        mongoClient.find("user",new JsonObject(),res->{
            if (res.succeeded()){
                List<JsonObject> jsonObjects=res.result();
                String name="ali";
                LOGGER.warn(jsonObjects.toString());
            }
            else{
                String name="name";
            }

        });
```

Mongodb Config comes below that contains db_name , port , host and more options that I need to connect to database .These Options work correctly for mongodb synchronize client (I used before).

```
"mongodb": {
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : 27017,
    "db_name":"amibackend",
    "maxPoolSize" : 50,
    "minPoolSize" : 25,
    "maxIdleTimeMS" : 300000,
    "maxLifeTimeMS" : 3600000,
    "waitQueueMultiple"  : 10,
    "waitQueueTimeoutMS" : 10000,
    "maintenanceFrequencyMS" : 2000,
    "maintenanceInitialDelayMS" : 500
  }
```

================================================

Dependencies of this project:(Vert.x)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.3</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-mongo-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you add your dependencies to the post ? This looks like a jar compatibility issue. Specifically check if the mongo asyn driver version is compatible with the  Vert Client you are using.

Comment: added dependencies.@Veeram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you got a problem with the version of mongodb driver.
I would recommend that you upgrade the mongodb driver.

[current version of ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/12895970ae008b4d83378f79dc8fdd54208084c5/driver-core/src/main/com/mongodb/internal/async/ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java)

[history version of ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/b008974f2355814712f99e03efb229ceecf9d3ca/driver-core/src/main/com/mongodb/internal/async/ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java)

Comment: I didn't specify the version of mongo driver. I just use `vert.x mongodb client` @Tan

Comment: Thanks .the problem was with mongo driver. Exist synchronize mongo driver that make conflict with async mongo driver.